# Recursion does not print error but is stuck

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

My Code seems to get stuck in the first recursion. My IDE also does not print out any StackOverflow error or other errors.

The purpose of this algorithm is finding all colored areas of an image.

Any help on solving this would be appreciated.

P.S: pixels[] is an array of rgb values of any "PImage".

```
public class Test {

  PImage finalImage;

  public Test(PImage pImage) {
    finalImage = pImage.get(0, 0, pImage.width, pImage.height);
  }

  public void floodFill() {
    int targetColor;
    for (int x = 0; x < finalImage.width; x+=3) {
      for (int y = 0; y < finalImage.height; y+=3) {
        targetColor = finalImage.pixels[index(x, y, finalImage)];
        flood4(x, y, targetColor, color(69, 69, 69));
      }
    }
  }

  public void flood4(int x, int y, int target, int replacement) {

    finalImage.loadPixels();

    int currentColor = finalImage.pixels[index(x, y, finalImage)];

    if (currentColor != target) {
      return;
    }

    if (currentColor == replacement) {
      return;
    }

    if (!inBounds(x, y, finalImage)) {
      return;
    }

    finalImage.pixels[index(x, y, finalImage)] = replacement;

    finalImage.updatePixels();

    flood4(x+1, y, target, replacement);
    flood4(x-1, y, target, replacement);
    flood4(x, y+1, target, replacement);
    flood4(x, y-1, target, replacement);
  }

  PImage getImage() {
    return finalImage.get(0, 0, finalImage.width, finalImage.height);
  }
}

boolean inBounds(int x, int y, PImage img) {
  return x>-1&&x<img.width&&y>-1&&y<img.height;
}
```

Comment: Use Debug facility of your IDE and run your code step-by-step.

Comment: If i had to guess i would say it's because you keep making multiple calls with `x+1` and then `x-1` right after that. (Same for y). Just imagine if x reaches the maximum value (lets say 100) until it is no longer in bounds of your image. Then you call the recursiv function with `x=(100-1)` and then in that method call you will call the function again with `x=((100-1)+1)`. So your recursiv function will always alternate on the last pixels of your bounds.

Comment: Sounds good, ill add if statements. What about my inBounds() Method that was supposed to prevent it? its working as ive used it in other classes, but it doesnt prevent this error?

Comment: FYI we dont see the inBounds() method implementation.

Comment: ill add it if you need it

Comment: @man420 Assuming your inBounds method does what it says then it would work to prevent infinite recursion if you only moved your x/y pointers into one direction. But s it currently is your call `flood4(x+1, y, target, replacement);` might trigger the inbounds method and stop the recursion in that path, but then right after returning you do `flood4(x-1, y, target, replacement);` and suddenly your next call of `flood4(x+1, y, target, replacement);` will be in bounds again and the loop starts again.

Comment: how do i fix this (;-;)

Comment: You could try to just remove the lines `flood4(x-1, y, target, replacement);` and `flood4(x, y-1, target, replacement);`and see if it successfully finishes and does what you intend it to do. Since you start at x=0/y=0 it should cover all pixels just with the x+1/y+1 path. **However** this would make the function no longer go over all pixels if someone would ever call with a starting point different to 0/0.

Comment: It still doesnt work. For instance if i put print(false) in the nested for loops, it will only print once. Its still stuck somewhere in the recursion

Comment: it does work if i only leave this flood4(x-1, y, target, replacement);

Comment: does it work for small inputs like width and height is 3?